# Change logo in OrientDB 2.2.x Studio

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

How can I change the logo in Studio? I have been searching for the location of the files, but I cannot see them. Also I have been searching for the files in Studio self.

Comment: Here it is on OrientDB's GitHub: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio/blob/master/app/img/orient_db.png

Comment: Hi, I do not have a studio folder and cannot see an install base on my server?.? Seems like studio is there hidden?

Answer (score 0):

solution: in plugin directory unzip studio-x.x.zip change the files within the zip (also image/logo) and then zip the folder again. Restart the server and its changed.